# While using a pointer to a 2D array to print any column out of it. How does the pointer point to the next element in the column?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], (*p)[NUM_COLS], i=5;
//pointer can point to an array of length 'Length Columns'
```

Let's iterate it

```
for(p=&a[0]; p<&a[NUM_ROWS]; p++){

  (*p)[i]=0;

}
```

My (incomplete) understanding is that p is pointing to the location of array ' a's ' 0th index location, this is stored as a 1-D array of length [NUM_COLS]. How is this making the array column 'i' to reset itself to 0. How is pointer jumping to next column location?

I know that a 'p + i' refers to 'address of a +  4*i bytes' so how is 'address of a + x bytes' happening in column wise iteration using pointer to an array,

Comment: It doesn't. p++ makes p point to the next **row**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` is a pointer to a whole row of the array, so `p++` makes it point to the next row. By setting the `[i]` entry to 0 in every row, you set the entire `i`-th column to 0.

> I know that a 'p + i' refers to 'address of a + 4*i bytes' so how is 'address of a + x bytes' happening in column wise iteration using pointer to an array,

This is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this expression in the for loop

```
p=&a[0];
```

you could just write

```
p = a;
```

Array designators used in expressions are implicitly converted (with rare exceptions) to pointers to their first elements.

So dereferencing the pointer `*p` you will get the element of the two-dimensional array pointed to by the pointer `p`. In case of the array `a` elements of the array has the type `int[NUM_COLS]`.

In turn the array designator `*p` used in the expression `(*p)[i]` also is converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int *`. And the expression `(*p)[i]` yields the i-th element of the one-dimensional array pointed to by the pointer `p`.

The for loop can look like

```
for( p = a; p < a + NUM_ROWS; p++ ) 
{
  (*p)[i]=0;
}
```

That is the i-th element of each "row" of the two dimensional array is set to 0.

To make it more clear consider a one dimensional array.

```
int a[NUM_ELEMENTS};
```

then a pointer to the first element of the array looks like

```
int *p1 = a;
```

A pointer to the whole array as one object looks like

```
int ( *p2 )[NUM_ELEMENTS] = &a;
```

And you may write

```
p1 = *p2;
```

because the expression `*p2` yields the array `a`.

As for your statement

> I know that a 'p + i' refers to 'address of a + 4*i bytes' so how is
> 'address of a + x bytes' happening in column wise iteration using
> pointer to an array,

then actually the expression `p + i` refers to the i-th element of the two dimensional array the offset of the address of which is equal to the value `i * sizeof( int[NUM_COLS] )` that is equivalent to `i * NUM_COLS * sizeof( int )`.